# Do not or does not?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, do-support

Which sentence is correct when comparing things. For example:

> 1. "Display **do** not have black spot"
> 2. "Display **does** not have spot"

another example:

> 1. "Theorem **do** not have a proof"
> 2. "Theorem **does** not have a proof".

Comment: Generally, with singular things, you use *does*. With things that are plural, you use *do*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The display (singular) DOES not have..."

"The cows (plural) DO not have..."

This is similar to most verbs, including "Go":

```
 The cows go home together. 
 The cow goes home by himself.
```

- When the subject is plural (or the pronouns I/we/they), the verb
  typically does not end in an "s" (or "es"). *"Dogs go..."*

  When the subject is singular, or (the pronouns he/she/it), the verb ending is
  usually "s" or "es": *"He goes..."*

Most verbs, including Go, Try, Do, Play, Want, Need, Take, Eat, Sleep -- are conjugated with an "s/es" ending for singular subjects.

"Do" is just a little unusual, because the pronunciation for the singular and plural subjects are different. That is unlike "Go" and all the other verbs listed above, for which adding "s/es" at the end does not change the sound of the vowel. "Go/Goes" have the same long "O" sound. "Do/Does ('Doo'/'duhz')" sound different.